# How can I align my wallpaper to top left instead of center in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, desktop, desktop-customization

How can I align my wallpaper to top left instead of center in Windows 7? I know enough not to use stretch...

Comment: As in pinned and stretched or pinned with solid colour to fill?

Comment: Isn't Fill or Fit doing the trick assuming your image is the same size as the desktop? Or are you actually wanting gaps on the bottom and right sides of the image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works in any OS, not just Win7:

1. Create an empty image the same resolution as your desktop in your favorite image editing app.
2. Copy/Paste your desired wallpaper onto the empty image.
3. Move around as you see fit using your favorite image editing app.
4. Set wallpaper to the one made by image editing app.